# Selenium Error-- Can't be able to run Firefox

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium

I am trying to run Selenium in Eclipse. When running as TestNG it is not able to open Firefox. It closes as soon as it opens. It shows "Server not found" in the Firefox and the session is `null` in console. How to solve this?

Comment: Excuse me, but how is this java related?

Comment: can you please put your setup code here so we can see what might be wrong?

Comment: So you are using Selenium RC? If so, did you start the RC server from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when either:

-The version is incompatible

OR

-The installation path given in the code is wrong

OR

-The path to firefox has spaces in between (for selenium 3.0 above)